# Android: Bitmap.createBitmap with OutOfMemoryException - A Bug?

Tags: java, android, exception, memory, bitmap

I know that this theme was written a lot of, but I cannot find a solution in this threads.

I have a bitmap with a HD size and want to rotate it. But if I create a new Bitmap with Bitmap.createBitmap (with the same resolution) I get a OutOfMemoryException. At this point I have only one Bitmap in usage in my app! 
If I search for this problem I found solutions with "call recycle()" or "set Options", but all this things do not work. The second problem is that the available memory is very great. I log the size of the available memory and get 451 MB. This is the last call before I create the new Bitmap in HD resolution. I believe that my app use at this moment ca. 30MB of memory.

Ergo, my question: Is there a bug in the Bitmap.createBitmap method? If it is so, what is the work around?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: An Android App can't take all the device's available memory, there's a limit on all device for one app, and it vary between the devices. An app must ensure only 16MB as specified by Android. So if you've already taken 30MB and you need to create an HD bitmap, you won't have enough space to allocate in your app.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details like the size of the picture (bytes and resolution), resolution of the screen and of course your source code. Do you create and rotate with one call or separately?